# How can I represent a list of words and related words in a relational structure?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a list of `header words` and `words` as below and I am trying to understand how best to represent these in a relational table:

```
Header      Other
Words       Words

abandon     abandoned, abandoning, abandonment, abandons
abstract    abstraction, abstractions, abstractly, abstracts
access      accessed, accesses, accessibility, accessible, accessing, inaccessible  access
accommodate accommodated, accommodates, accommodating, accommodation    accommodate
accompany   accompanied, accompanies, accompaniment, accompanying, unaccompanied    accompany
accumulate  accumulated, accumulating, accumulation, accumulates
```

The problem is that for every word I have additional information such as pronunciation.

What I am thinking of is two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Word] (
    [WordId]         INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Word]           NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    [Pronounciation] NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [Other columns follow ...
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordRelationship] (
    [WordRelationshipId]  INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [HeaderWordId]        INT NOT NULL,
    [OtherWordId]         INT NOT NULL,
)
```

I would like to get some suggestions from the members here

Comment: This looks a bit like stemming.  Any reason you are rolling your own?   Full-text indexing might be able to do what you need if you can tell us more about what your overall goal is.

Comment: @wBob: Storing "additional information such as pronunciation" sounds to me like this may be more than just for full-text search support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @David-Spillet mentioned, I would recommend against the `IDENTITY` column in the junction table.  I would recommend creating a clustered index with a primary key on both columns, such as:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.WordRelationship (
    HeaderWordId        INT NOT NULL,
    OtherWordId         INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_WordRelationship
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (HeaderWordId, OtherWordId)
);
```

The `WordRelationshipId` column is unnecessary, and will increase the size of the table by 50%.

If you really want to keep the size of the table to an absolute minimum, you may want to ensure only a single variation of each relationship can exist.  For example, consider the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.WordRelationship') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.WordRelationship;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Word') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Word;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Word(
    WordId INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Word
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , Word NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
    , Pronounciation NVARCHAR(100) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.WordRelationship (
    HeaderWordId INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_WordRelationship_HeaderWordId 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Word(WordId)
    , OtherWordId INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_WordRelationship_OtherWordId 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Word(WordId)
    , CONSTRAINT PK_WordRelationship
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (HeaderWordId, OtherWordId)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Word (Word)
VALUES (N'Word')
    , (N'Words');

INSERT INTO dbo.WordRelationship (HeaderWordId, OtherWordId)
VALUES (1,2)
    , (2,1);

SELECT w1.Word
    , w2.Word
FROM dbo.Word w1
    INNER JOIN dbo.WordRelationship wr ON w1.WordId = wr.HeaderWordId
    INNER JOIN dbo.Word w2 ON wr.OtherWordId = w2.WordId
```

The output:

[image]

Pretty clearly, the 2nd row is not really required since the 1st row already captures the relationship.  You can prevent that by only inserting rows if the complement does not exist.  I've created a stored procedure to do the inserts, which returns the number of rows inserted:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.InsertWordRelationship') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.InsertWordRelationship;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertWordRelationship
(
    @HeaderWordId INT
    , @OtherWordId INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @RetVal INT;
    INSERT INTO dbo.WordRelationship (HeaderWordId, OtherWordId)
    SELECT @HeaderWordId, @OtherWordId
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM dbo.WordRelationship wr 
        WHERE (wr.HeaderWordId = @HeaderWordId 
            AND wr.OtherWordId = @OtherWordId)
            OR (wr.OtherWordId = @HeaderWordId 
            AND wr.HeaderWordId = @OtherWordId)
            );
    SET @RetVal = @@ROWCOUNT;
    RETURN @RetVal;
END
GO
```

The procedure uses a single atomic statement which is unlikely to cause deadlocks.

Now, if you insert (1,2) then try to insert (2,1), it will fail:

This inserts a row:

```
DECLARE @InsertedCount INT;

SET @InsertedCount = 0;
EXEC @InsertedCount = dbo.InsertWordRelationship 1,2;
IF @InsertedCount = 1 PRINT 'Inserted' ELSE PRINT 'Not Inserted';
```

But this doesn't:

```
SET @InsertedCount = 0;
EXEC @InsertedCount = dbo.InsertWordRelationship 2,1;
IF @InsertedCount = 1 PRINT 'Inserted' ELSE PRINT 'Not Inserted';
```

This shows the rows in the table:

```
SELECT w1.Word
    , w2.Word
FROM dbo.Word w1
    INNER JOIN dbo.WordRelationship wr ON w1.WordId = wr.HeaderWordId
    INNER JOIN dbo.Word w2 ON wr.OtherWordId = w2.WordId
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That is pretty much how you have to do it. The relationship table for a many-to-many link like that is often called a junction table (though goes by many other names on occasion: map table, mapping table, bridge table, ...).

If you have more than one class of relationship between words (abbreviation, antonym, synonim, ..) than that should be in the junction table too.

If you don't have multiple relationship types then there may be no need to have WordRelationshipId: the most efficient way to store what you currently have in SQL Server is just `HeaderWordId, WordID` with the two columns together being the primary key and that key being clustered (though as a matter of style/consistency some people prefer to have a separate surrogate key for all entities, and some frameworks baulk at composite PKs, so YMMV).